# Program that determines whether an array is a subset of another array

Tags: c

Hello I'm trying to write a program about subsets and my problem is that whenever I try to run the program, it's automatically saying that "Y is a not subset of X" even though it is a subset. Can someone help me with this? This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main()
{


int i, j, size1, size2, flag;

printf("S U B S E T S\n\n");
printf("Enter number of digits for Array X: ");
scanf("%d", &size1);

int array1[size1];

printf("Enter number of digits for Array Y: ");
scanf("%d", &size2);

int array2[size2];

printf("\n");
printf("Enter %d digits for Array X: ", size1);
for(i = 0; i < size1; i++)
    {
    scanf("%d", &array1[i]);
    }

printf("\n");
printf("Enter %d digits for Array Y: ", size2);

for(i = 0; i < size2; i++)
    {
    scanf("%d", &array2[i]);
    }

printf("\n\n");

for(i = 0; i < size2; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < size1; j++)
        if(array2[i] == array1[j])
        flag++;         

        if(flag == size1)
        {
        printf("Array X is a subset of Array Y");
        }
        else
        {
        printf("Array X is not a subset of Array Y");
        }
return 0;
```

}

Comment: What did you do after you found out the program doesn't work? Did you do any debugging? Like running your program in a debugger and/or adding more debug print statements? [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: `for (int j=1; j<=n;j++)` and `for (j = 0; j < m; j++)`. Indices look messed up. Sometimes you start from `1` and sometimes from `0`.

Comment: Hello @kaylum my program works fine if the elements of array are already defined. But when I change it to user input, thats when the problem occurs.

Comment: That's nice to know. But I have already pointed out one big problem in your code. It doesn't matter if it appears to work under some limited conditions. It's still wrong and you should fix it. Unless you believe it's not wrong in which case please explain why.

Comment: I have reconstructed my code and still get the same result :(

Answer (score 0):

It is working with very minor changes. Just loop from 0 and use < instead of <=.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int isSubset(int arr1[], int arr2[], int m, int n) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            if (arr2[i] == arr1[j])
                break;
        }
        if (j == m)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    int arr1[20];
    int arr2[20];
    int m, n;

    printf("How many elements of X you want to store?\n");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    printf("How many elements of Y you want to store?\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        printf("\nEnter %d X values to be stored:\n", m);
        scanf("%d", &arr1[i]);
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        printf("\nEnter %d Y values to be stored:\n", n);
        scanf("%d", &arr2[j]);
    }

    m = sizeof(arr1) / sizeof(arr1[0]);
    n = sizeof(arr2) / sizeof(arr2[0]);

    if (isSubset(arr1, arr2, m, n))
        printf("Y is a subset of X \n");
    else
        printf("Y is not a subset of X\n");

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```